# Simple way to test my load balancer from behind (inside) its LAN

Tags: load-balancing

I have a **3 DSL load balancer** with, say, **1MB/seg download** speed.
In order to **check its correct behavior** from any of the **computers connected to** this load balancer and see if traffic (download, at least) is being multiplexed through all the 3 lines, I do:

```
curl -o /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip
```

and I wait to obtain a **full 1MB/seg** download speed, like:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 48  500M   48  241M    0     0   947k      0  0:09:00  0:04:21  0:04:39 1007k
```

If speed is not at **its full speed** (1MB/seg) I cancel the `curl` command and star it again, until I finally get 3 `curl` consoles running at 1MB/seg speed. As long as this is my maximum download speed, I consider then that the balance load is performing all right.

Is there a better/simpler way?

I have found methods to test load balancing that must be executed from **the own** load balancer. But I think it could be useful to know about some test that could be performed on any computer/device **inside the LAN** that receives internet from this load balancer.

Multi-platform methods if possible, please (as long as there are `curl` version for most operating systems, this can be considered as a multi-platform solution).
Ideas for command-line methods are prefered. Accepted for GUI (like web browsing, Java, and so on).
Suggestions for upload tests accepted too.

Answer (score 0):

From any of the computers behind (inside the scope of, feeded by) your load balancer, start any **bittorrent** download (a very shared file, preferably: many seeds or at least leechers).

The download speed should easily increase above the speed of one of your internet lines. It would even probably reach the **maximum** of all the lines.

Method supposedly valid for both **download and upload**.